# Error: "microsoft.cache/redis is not a supported platform metric namespace

Tags: azure, redis, metrics, azure-rm-template, azure-monitoring

In my current Azure release pipeline I get the following error:

```
"Code": "BadRequest", 
"Message": "{"code":"BadRequest","message":"microsoft.cache/redis is not a supported platform metric namespace, supported ones are...
<-snip->
```

With a long list of supported names which is indeed missing "Microsoft.Cache/Redis".
This is strange because

- according to the (Microsoft) site on [Supported Metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/metrics-supported#microsoftcacheredis)
  Microsoft.Cache/Redis is a supported namespace
- this morning (4/16/2020, 11:08:26 AM CET) the same step in the same pipeline with
  the same ARM template **did** work .

Did somebody remove or renamed this namespace with updating the documentation?

If so what is the new name?

Comment: Moreover the same template rolls-out seamlessly on a Development environment while on Test and Production it fails

Comment: can you share with us the template ?(hide any sensitive data)

Comment: I retried the same release last Friday and miracle the error did not re-occur. I assume Microsoft introduced the  error and removed it again.